# Spark Structured Streaming - cleanSource is not working

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, aws-glue, spark-structured-streaming

I have a simple Spark Structured Streaming job that streams data from two parquet tables, persisted in AWS S3, into their respective delta table location.

The streaming job is working fine such that the data is being streamed to the delta table in an expected manner.

However, completed files, i.e. the underlying Parquet files of the source location, are not being cleaned up after the streaming job, even though I have specified the `cleanSource` option to `archive`, as well as provided the `sourceArchiveDir` option.

The behaviour that I am expecting here is that these underlying Parquet files are moved to the archive location, specified by `sourceArchiveDir`.

The job is running in AWS Glue 3.0, which uses Spark 3.1.1. I am certain the `cleanSource` option is being picked up, because I tried omitting the `sourceArchiveDir` option, and the Spark JVM threw an exception right away about a missing `sourceArchiveDir`.

Below is a simplified version of my code pattern:

```py
from typing import List

from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType


def run_job(spark: SparkSession, tables: List[ParquetTableParam]):
    for table in tables:
        table_schema: StructType = schema_from_table(table)
        source, archive, checkpoint, destination = (
            table.source,      # e.g s3:/my-bucket/integration-data/parquet-table/123
            table.archive,     # e.g s3:/my-bucket/integration-data/parquet-archive
            table.checkpoint,  # e.g s3:/my-bucket/integration-data/delta-checkpoint
            table.destination, # e.g s3:/my-bucket/integration-data/delta-destination/123
        )

        stream_read = (
            spark.readStream.schema(table_schema)
            .format("parquet")
            .option("cleanSource", "archive")
            .option("sourceArchiveDir", archive)
            ## I have tried the below options, and they made no difference
            # .option("spark.sql.streaming.fileSource.cleaner.numThreads", "10")
            # .option("spark.sql.streaming.fileSource.log.compactInterval", "1")
            # .option("spark.sql.streaming.fileSource.log.cleanupDelay", "1")
            .load(source)
        )

        stream_write = (
            stream_read.writeStream.format("delta")
            .trigger(once=True)
            .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint)
            .option("path", destination)
        )

        stream_write.start()

    wait_for_streams(spark)


def wait_for_streams(spark: SparkSession):
    while len(spark.streams.active) > 0:
        spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
```

My suspicion here is that the cleaner thread, which is responsible for the cleaning operation, hasn't started doing its job at the time the streaming job finishes. However I haven't been able to find any documentation on this, or any way to "wait" for the cleaner thread to finish, similar to `spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()`.

Thank you for reading this post.

I would really appreciate it if anyone can offer a solution to help me with this, or at least provide an explanation for this behaviour.

Reference:

- https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html

EDIT 1:

After digging around the Spark codebase, I confirmed my initial suspicion that the cleaning/archiving is done on a seperate JVM thread, [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/faedcd91d554a00fc76116a0c188752cf036f907/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/FileStreamSource.scala#L436-L446).

Then, I did an experiment to configure the number of spark cleaner thread to 0, which effectively forces the main thread to do the cleaning. It resulted in **some** of the data being archived after the first streaming job, more than if it were to be done on the separate thread, but not all - because the Python process just ends before the cleaning finishes .

From what I have seen I believe this is pretty much how Pyspark behaves with `triggerOnce` and I don't think there is any solution to overcome this via configuration.

Comment: Mb not correctly question, but why u are using file streaming? Simples to write a batch processing with moving source where u need?

Comment: @РобертНадь My original expectation was that Spark Structured Streaming could be used for this task for its checkpoint and archiving feature. This would have been easier than to implement something myself.

Comment: So where you able to get the fix, because I am also encountering the same issue, only that the files are on my HDFS and I am using Spark 3.3.3 on a Virtual Machine